# Which database is used as In-Memory in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to develop my application without database rather than database i want to follow In-memory process which database i should refer with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlite like memory database.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify SQLite as you database engine and ":memory:" (without the quotes) as the name for your database.

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html